# Tabs click not working when using ng-repeat

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a script to add custom tabs on runtime.All the tabs are being created but for some reason those created with ng-repeat can't be selected, is like a plain label. What am I missing?

```
<ul class="clearfix tabs-list tabamount6 tabs">
    <li data-tab="tab-1">News</li>
    <li data-tab="tab-2">Meet the team</li>
    <li class="current" data-tab="tab-3">Related articles</li>
    <li data-tab="tab-4">Videos</li>
    <li ng-repeat="t in tabs" data-tab="ctab-{{t.Id}}">{{t.Title}}</li>
    <asp:Literal ID="AddNewTab" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
</ul>
```

Comment: What library does the code use to evaluare the `data-tabs` attribure and  generate the tabs?

Comment: Likely your tab library is processing `<li>` elements with a `data-tab` attribute on page load, but is unaware of the newly added tabs. You should look at the documentation for that tab library for how to notify it that new tabs have been added to the DOM.

Comment: The problem is that it's been around 10 years since I don't develop in ASP lol so I'm rusty AF. And this code is from someone else :( so the library that it's being used to control the tab click is superfish, any help you can provide about it and if will work for this purpose??

Comment: So a friend helped me already, to solve this I had to add ng-click="$event" to the list item and then create a new function in the controller scope :)